# Canonical form of skew-symmetric bilinear function and its transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Reduce the skew-symmetric bilinear function to canonical form and find the matrix of the transformation.

$$\varphi(x,y)=x_1y_2-x_2y_1+2x_1y_3-2x_3y_1-x_1y_4+x_4y_1+4x_2y_4-4x_4y_2+x_3y_4-x_4y_3$$

**My approach:** Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ is the given basis for vector space and the matrix of this form is $$B_{\varphi}^{(e)}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -4 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Let's find the new basis in the form $e'_1=e_1, e'_2=e_2$ and $e'_i=e_i+\dfrac{b_{2i}}{b_{12}}e_1-\dfrac{b_{1i}}{b_{12}}e_1$ for $i\geq 3$, where $b_{ij}$ are elements of the above matrix (we are finding the new basis in such a way that $\varphi(e'_1,e'_i)=\varphi(e'_2,e'_i)=0$ for $i\geq 3$).

Then one can show that $e'_3=e_3-2e_2$ and $e'_4=e_4+4e_1+e_2$.
Also basis calculation shows that $$\varphi(e'_3,e'_4)=\varphi(e_3-2e_2,e_4+4e_1+e_2)=b_{34}-2b_{24}+4b_{31}-2b_{21}+b_{32}=-13.$$ Let take the new basis $(e'')=\{e'_1,e'_2,-e'_3/13,e'_4\}$ and then it follows that in this basis the matrix has canonical form, i.e. $$B_{\varphi}^{(e'')}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ and the function has the following canonical form $$(u_1v_2-u_2v_1)+(u_3v_4-u_4v_3)$$ and the transformation matrix is this

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2/13 & -1/13 & 0 \\
4 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Can anyone say to me is my reasoning and the answers are correct, please?

Would be very thankful!

Comment: with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B0+%2C+1+%2C+2+%2C+-1%7D%2C%7B+-1+%2C+0+%2C+0+%2C+4+%7D%2C%7B+-2+%2C+0+%2C+0+%2C+1%7D%2C%7B+1+%2C+-4+%2C+-1+%2C+0+%7D%7D you can see the $J$ which is far from your try

Comment: Well, in Newman, Integral Matrices, there is a sort of Smith type canonical form for skew symmetric matrices with integer elements.

Comment: @janmarqz no, the intended canonical form is also skew symmetric and real; indeed, we can accomplish that with an integer matrix in $P^T BP =S$

Comment: @willjagy, so it is correct, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I have so far following Newman's recipe:

```
? s
%24 = 
[ 0  1  2 -1]

[-1  0  0  4]

[-2  0  0  1]

[ 1 -4 -1  0]

? rt
%25 = 
[1 0  0 0]

[0 1  0 0]

[4 1  0 1]

[0 2 -1 0]

? r
%26 = 
[1 0 4  0]

[0 1 1  2]

[0 0 0 -1]

[0 0 1  0]

? rt * s * r
%27 = 
[ 0 1 0  0]

[-1 0 0  0]

[ 0 0 0 -7]

[ 0 0 7  0]

?
```